# XSLT Parsing XML with &lt and &gt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that has a TextBlock that contains the below samplecode.

```
<TextBlock>
  <config>This is a config.</config>
  <path>This is a file path.</path>
</TextBlock>
```

The actual XML file contains the below

```
&lt;TextBlock&gt;
  &lt;config&gt;This is a config.&lt;/config&gt;
  &lt;path&gt;This is a file path.&lt;/path&gt;
&lt;/TextBlock&gt;
```

I'm trying to get the value of path tag using XSLT 1.0

```
<h1>
  <xsl:value-of select="/TextBlock/path" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</h1>
```

I don't get the value because the XML structure is broken due to &lt &gt.
Is there a way to get around this or convert `&lt` and `&gt` to `<` and `>` in XSLT?

Comment: Do you use a particular XSLT 1.0 processor? With some like MSXML or XslCompiledTransform it is rather straightforward to add an extension function to parse a string of XML into a node set so that you can then use XPath on it.

Comment: i'm using xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"

Comment: If that is the Java version of Xalan why don't you switch to Saxon 9.7 where you have XSLT 2.0 and XPath 3.0/3.1 function support for the `parse-xml` function? On the other hand Xalan Java I think allows you to use Java to write extension functions so check its documentation on how to do that and simply write a function that returns a DOM `Document` parsed from your string and it should work I think.

Comment: I hope this link can be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673672/handling-lt-gt-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 1):

Escaped XML is just a meaningless text string and cannot be parsed using XPath.

In the given example, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(/TextBlock, '&lt;path&gt;'), '&lt;/path&gt;')"/>
```

to extract the string `"This is a file path."`from the given document.

---

Alternatively, you could process the document twice: in the first pass, use `disable-output-escaping` to unescape the string, then use a second stylesheet on the resulting file to extract the contents of what will now be the `path` element.

---

### Added:

If your *entire* document is escaped as shown in your edited example, then it isn't an XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT (at least not XSLT 1.0)  at all.

Comment: Would this still work if we have multiple levels like

`&lt;TextBlock&gt;
  &lt;config&gt;This is a config.&lt;/config&gt;
  &lt;path&gt;This is a file path.&lt;/path&gt;
&lt;/TextBlock&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd have [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) available, you could pipe your files through it before processing it with XSLT.

For example: to process `input.xml` to `output.xml` you would execute

```
sed -e "s/&lt;/</g" input.xml | sed -e "s/&gt;/>/g" > output.xml
```

and then process `output.xml` with the XSLT processor of your choice.
This would convert all the `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities to the respective chars.

Comment: isn't there a way to handle it with in the XSLT ?

Comment: @user2628187: Converting an input and processing its output as input is AFAIK not possibile in XSLT in one step. The way I described using `sed` is ÁFAIK the easiest (and simplest) way to go,

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'&lt;test3&gt;'), '&lt;/test3&gt;')"/>